# What happened in this step of the derivation?(Getting Rid of a Square Root)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, physics, approximation

I am trying to follow along a simple derivation, and I don't really get this approximation.
$$L\bigg[1+\frac{\big(y\pm\frac{d}{2}\big)^2}{L^2}\bigg]^{1/2}\approx L\bigg[1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{(y\pm\frac{d}{2})^2}{L^2}\bigg]$$

This derivation assumes that $y<<L$. Is this operation some kind of taylor expansion? What is being expanded and/or what happens in that step?

(For context, this is a problem in trying to find the zones of constructive/destructive interference in a double-slit configuration.)

Comment: Without the full context it's difficult to tell

Comment: Yes, they're using the first two terms of the taylor expansion of $(1+x)^{1/2}$ around $x = 0$.

Comment: [Here](http://planetmath.org/taylorexpansionofsqrt1x) is a page with the corresponding expansion.  Additionally, $y\ll L$ ensures that the "$x$" in $(1+x)^{1/2}$ is small, so the expansion isn't too inacurate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It took me a minute to find out they're expanding around $\frac{(y\pm\frac{d}{2})^2}{L^2} =0$.